# Sorting NSArray which many contain number

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch, nsarray

I have an NSArray which is populated with objects from an NSMutableArray. Most of these object have integer values like "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", sometimes there is a name like "home", "far left", or "far right". I am trying to sort this array in Objective C. using sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:) works fine when I have less then 10 items in the array. but when it there are more I start getting "1", "10", "11", "12", "2", "3" type of stuff. Any help would be most appreciated. The code should not return anything. It just needs to sort and move on.

Original Code:

```
presetNamesSort = [[[NSMutableArray alloc]init]retain];

presetNamesSort = [presetNames sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can use `NSArray`'s `-sortedArrayUsingComparator:` method to get a sorted array using a custom block. I find this more convenient than `-sortedArrayUsingSelector:`, because you can declare the comparator inline, like so:

```
NSArray *unsortedArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Hello", @"4", @"Hi", @"5", @"2", @"10", @"1", nil];
NSArray *sortedArray = [unsortedArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(NSString *str1, NSString *str2) {
    return [str1 compare:str2 options:NSNumericSearch];
}];
```

This will return an array that looks like so:

```
(
    1,
    2,
    4,
    5,
    10,
    Hello,
    Hi
)
```

In general, it's pretty nice to use blocks because they eliminate the need to create random selectors that run amuk in your code.

Comment: We should mention, blocks require iOS 4 or newer. If that's the case, this answer is the most elegant. /@Ribbons

Comment: I have sort an array using your solution. it's work great. but i have another problem i have to sort an array using condition. like i have two values "Company" and "Date". if the company name is same then it check date which would be latest it first sort can you help me out ?

Comment: @CocoaMatters You would have to use `NSArray`'s `-sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:` method and use [`NSSortDescriptor`s](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSSortDescriptor_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to sort based on multiple criteria. You can create two sort descriptors (one based on the 'company' key and the other on the 'date' key), and it will sort using both.

Comment: @ItaiFerber I know that i want to use NSSortDescriptor for sorting. but my case id nested like if same name came to sorting it check the date for sorting. in my array an object contain two value "company" and "date".

Comment: @CocoaMatters Sort descriptors handle the nesting for you. Create an `NSArray` with two sort descriptors: the first for 'company', the second for 'date'. The sorted array will be sorted first by company, then for entries with the same company, by date.

Answer (score 1):

try using `-[NSString compare:options:]` with `NSNumericSearch`. To use that with `-sortedArrayUsingSelector:` you have to wrap the compare call into a separate category method on `NSString`:

```
- (NSComparisonResult)numericCompare:(NSString *)aString {
    return [self compare:aString options:NSNumericSearch];
}
```

Comment: presetNamesSort = [[[NSMutableArray alloc]init]retain];
presetNamesSort = [presetNames sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];

Comment: That is the original code use get the result, presetNames is an NSMuttableArray and presetNamesSort is a regular Array. So I need presetNamesSort to contain the sorted content of presetNames

Answer (score 0):

For sorting Descending

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [arrayToSort sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(NSString *str1, NSString *str2) {
    return [str1 compare:str2 options:NSNumericSearch];
}];
sortedArray = [[sortedArray reverseObjectEnumerator] allObjects];`
```

And for asending

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [arrayToSort sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(NSString *str1, NSString *str2) {
    return [str1 compare:str2 options:NSNumericSearch];
}];
```

Comment: Hi, @SGRKDL - I thought you should know that code formatting for multiple lines is done with four spaces before each line. Apostrophes are used for shorter things like a 'ClassName'.  I adjusted for you, so you can see.