# Crazy array sorting in tableView! sortedArrayUsingSelector help?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, sorting, nsarray

My tableView app loads the data into the table view.
Everything works perfectly, but the array sorting is kind of messed, like you can see in the picture below. I thought about using the sortedArrayUsingSelector, to straighten things up, but I'm not sure which "sorting method" I should use.
[image: You can see, the numbers don't go like 1. 2. 3. 4. 5. etc, but weird...]

How can I sort this so the cells are sorted according the numbers? Like the order would be 1. 2. 3. 4. 5. etc NOT 1. 10. 11. 12. 13. 14. 2. 3. ?

Thanks a lot in advance!!

Comment: How are you loading in this data/ what type of structure is the persistent datastore (i.e plist with nsdictionary/nsarray or core data)

Comment: The array sort looks correct. `10` sorts after `1.` and before `2.`. Remember, the computer doesn't recognize numbers the same way you do.

Comment: ok, but how can I do it the way I want? @Michael its a plist :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

And a two-liner:

```
NSSortDescriptor *descriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:nil ascending:YES comparator:^(id obj1, id obj2) { return [obj1 compare:obj2 options:NSNumericSearch]; }];
rowTitleArray = [rowTitleArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:descriptor]];
```

Comment: hmm ok.. but how can I implement it in the "arraySortedWithSelector" method?

Comment: btw. I really appreciate you help... It fascinates me how people are willing to help complete strangers for almost no reward...

Comment: Chuck `arraySortedUsingSelectors`. Use its counterpart `arraySortedUsingDescriptors`.

Comment: I'm not really sure how :/ Anything more you can tell me?

Comment: Oh, figured out... the code now is...

 NSSortDescriptor *descriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:nil ascending:YES comparator:^(id obj1, id obj2) { return [obj1 compare:obj2 options:NSNumericSearch]; }];
 NSString *zapas = [[[[[sharedManager.rootDict objectForKey:key] objectForKey:@"zapasy"] allKeys] sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:descriptor]] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = zapas;

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for this convoluted approach, but this does work...

```
NSArray *rowTitleArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                          @"10. Tenth", 
                          @"15. Fifteenth", 
                          @"13. Thirteenth", 
                          @"1. First", 
                          @"2. Second", 
                          @"22. TwentySecond", nil];

NSMutableArray *dictionaryArray = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSString *original in rowTitleArray) {
    NSString *numberString = [[original componentsSeparatedByString:@"."] objectAtIndex:0];
    NSNumber *number = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[numberString intValue]];
    NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                          number, @"number", original, @"rowTitle", nil];
    [dictionaryArray addObject:dict];
}
NSSortDescriptor *descriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"number" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortedDictionaryArray = [dictionaryArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:
                                  [NSArray arrayWithObject:descriptor]];
NSMutableArray *sortedRowTitles = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSDictionary *dict in sortedDictionaryArray) {
    [sortedRowTitles addObject:[dict objectForKey:@"rowTitle"]];
}
rowTitleArray = [NSArray arrayWithArray:sortedRowTitles];

NSLog(@"%@", rowTitleArray);
```

Output:

```
    "1. First",
    "2. Second",
    "10. Tenth",
    "13. Thirteenth",
    "15. Fifteenth",
    "22. TwentySecond"
```

I will try to think of a more elegant solution.

Comment: hmm thanks a lot... if you find a more elegant solution please let me know... I found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4588542/sorting-nsarray-which-many-contain-number but can't get smart out of it :( maybe it might help you...

Comment: See my new two-liner above. I think this is the shortest also fastest method. (Perhaps also the most elegant one.)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more elegant solution:

```
NSInteger intSort(id num1, id num2, void *context) {
    NSString *n1 = (NSString *) num1;
    NSString *n2 = (NSString *) num2;
    n1 = [[n1 componentsSeparatedByString:@"."] objectAtIndex:0];
    n2 = [[n2 componentsSeparatedByString:@"."] objectAtIndex:0];
    if ([n1 intValue] < [n2 intValue]) {
        return NSOrderedAscending;
    }
    else if ([n1 intValue] > [n2 intValue]) {
        return NSOrderedDescending;
    }
    return NSOrderedSame;
}

rowTitleArray = [rowTitleArray sortedArrayUsingFunction:intSort context:NULL];
```