# How retrireve array from dictionary

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray, nsdictionary

I have 2 columns in my Sqlite table 1.DetailsID & 2.Detailstype

i have stored values id: int and detailstype :varchar.

set the id with string in sqlite select query as

```
while(sqlite3_step(selectPrefer) == SQLITE_ROW)
            {                
                NSString *detailsString = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectPrefer, 1)];
                int detailsId = (int)sqlite3_column_int(selectPrefer, 0);

                [detailsData setObject:detailsString forKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:detailsId ]];

            }
```

I have a NSmutable dictionary like this:

```
(


         0 = "˚F";
        12 = Activity;
        11 = BM;
        7 = "Heart Rate";
        6 = "Nose Problem";
        2 = Rx;
        1 = BP;
        10 = Food;
        9 = "Stress Level";
        8 = Glucose;
        5 = "Pain Level";
        4 = Weight;
        3 = Events;
}
i can get arrays using allKeys & allValues but these are not in order
```

Now i want seperate arrays like

```
       {
             0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12

        )
```

both values & keys In ascending order with respect to keys

```
(
            "˚F";
         Activity;
         BM;
         "Heart Rate";
         "Nose Problem";
         Rx;
         BP;
         Food;
         "Stress Level";
         Glucose;
         "Pain Level";
         Weight;
         Events;
)
```

with out any modifications in sqlite query
- what to do thannks in advance

Answer (score 4):

You should use the allKeys and allValues property of the [dictionay](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsdictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html) :

> allKeys Returns a new array containing the dictionary’s keys.
>
> allValues Returns a new array containing the dictionary’s values.

Try this :

```
NSArray *keysArray = [yourDictionnay allKeys];
NSArray *valuesArray = [yourDictionnay allvalues];
```

Hope this helps,
Vincent

Comment: I want to retrieve keys  in ascending order order like (0,1,2,3,....,11,12).
how?

Comment: Have a look at this SO question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4588542/sorting-nsarray-which-many-contain-number

Comment: I want allValues that are sorted by allKeys

Answer (score 1):

you need both allValues and allkeys.

```
NSArray *values = [dictionary allValues];
NSArray *keys  =  [dicitoary allKeys];
```

Comment: I want allValues that are sorted by allKeys